# Find nearest timestamps to log and chart events

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

The spreadsheet is [linked here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IGzlSBfQGiMqHvtxeUHG_ZMRidKwjU_r4LQ9BV_jgcg/edit?usp=sharing/). The easy part of the spreadsheet I could do, calculate the duration of a single event. Now I want the spreadsheet to calculate the extended data from the data existing on the same sheet using formulas if possible.

The shared spreadsheet is logging a sensor, both when it trips and when it clears as a single record (with 2 events - start/stop). Then it calculates the duration of the alarm. I want to also compare with other records on the same sheet, dynamically populating the cells of each individual event. Unfortunately, I don't know how to find the nearest timestamps from other record numbers.

I could manually find these figures with tons of sorting and resorting, but the file can only be sorted by event record number only, so I need formula help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 0]

**E2**:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(B2-B1, "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

**F2**:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW())),{INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW()), INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW())},2,0)
```

**G2**:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(C2-C1, "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

**H2**:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(INDIRECT("C2:C"&ROW())),{INDIRECT("C2:C"&ROW()), INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW())},2,0)
```

**I2**:

```
=TEXT(MAX(INDIRECT("B2:C"&ROW()))-B2, "[h]:mm:ss")
```

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1umqndHHbxnnMa3mP-x3__vuL0mCTjHxtvcVd2QSGVwU/edit?usp=sharing)**

---

[image: 0]

**C2**:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(B2-INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B:B, B:B<B2, B:B<>""),1,0),1,1), "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

**D2**:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B:B, B:B<B2, B:B<>""),1,0),1,1), {B:B,A:A}, 2,0))
```

Comment: Your work has me 90% to my goal, thank you for taking the time to put it all together and showing the work.

Comment: If you have the time to take one more look I can explain what I failed to explain initially. I copied your work onto the same spreadsheet I shared in the original post.

When I said nearest for the final 2 columns I meant nearest to the start time of the new event, not static from the previous record. So record #3 has a start time of 00:02. E3 is calculated correctly, but only static. E4 should have that same result. 

Lastly i10 should be showing the data from B8 with, J10 indicating which column was the result pulled from (Start/Stop) and K10 would indicate that it came from A8.

Comment: for J9 you mean nearest green cell from a yellow cell? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg4EK.png

Comment: Yes, but please let me clear, I really appreciate the work you've done, it is really good. Columns D, E & G can all be static with the B2-B1 thing. But columns J&K are crucial to my plan, as mentioned that data is calculated based on the time difference of Column B cell* and will compare the record that is nearest in time  duration since last start activity across all records (excluding itself of course). Ideally comparing both start column and start columns then choosing the shortest of the two, but for now I am happy just getting a start to start comparative calculation. Thank you again!

Comment: So looking at your image, the J9 result would be the comparison of C9 against the entire range of B2:B10, with the shortest duration being the calculated result, effectively B9.

Comment: try J2: `=TEXT(C2-MIN(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B$2:B)+1)), "[h]:mm:ss")` and drag down

Comment: I am sorry, I have had 2 typos that I couldn't edit which has made this all very confusing and complex. I will simplify this. I want D3 to use a formula to find the record in column B that is nearest in history to row corresponding to the formula was called on. The resulting record number would go into column D, and the time difference for the duration into column C on the corresponding row. The attached image shows the results I want, notice the results skip around on the sheet. - https://imgur.com/OO0MBDR

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you. That is 2 times your formulas did really cool things with Vlookup. I am gonna spend the next few days trying to master that function, it seems super powerful. Thank you very much for the help.